# Iterate/Enumerate over a subset of N^5 in Python

Tags: python, iteration, enumeration

I have a subset of ℕ<sup>5</sup>, five dimensional vectors whose elements lie in the natural numbers. This subset is defined as the product of intervals [*a*<sub>1</sub>, *a*<sub>2</sub>]×[*b*<sub>1</sub>, *b*<sub>2</sub>]×...×[*f*<sub>1</sub>, *f*<sub>2</sub>], and I would like to enumerate the subsets of size 1, that is the vectors (*x*<sub>1</sub>, *x*<sub>2</sub>, *x*<sub>3</sub>, *x*<sub>4</sub>, *x*<sub>5</sub>) where *x*<sub>1</sub> is in [*a*<sub>1</sub>, *a*<sub>2</sub>], *x*<sub>2</sub> is in [*b*<sub>1</sub>, *b*<sub>2</sub>] etc. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [*cartesian product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) and you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to compute it:

```
a = [0, 1]
b = [2, 3]
c = [4, 5]
d = [6, 7]
e = [8, 9]

for subset in product(a, b, c, d, e):
    print(subset)
```

**output**

```
(0, 2, 4, 6, 8)
(0, 2, 4, 6, 9)
(0, 2, 4, 7, 8)
(0, 2, 4, 7, 9)
(0, 2, 5, 6, 8)
(0, 2, 5, 6, 9)
(0, 2, 5, 7, 8)
(0, 2, 5, 7, 9)
(0, 3, 4, 6, 8)
(0, 3, 4, 6, 9)
(0, 3, 4, 7, 8)
(0, 3, 4, 7, 9)
(0, 3, 5, 6, 8)
(0, 3, 5, 6, 9)
(0, 3, 5, 7, 8)
(0, 3, 5, 7, 9)
(1, 2, 4, 6, 8)
(1, 2, 4, 6, 9)
(1, 2, 4, 7, 8)
(1, 2, 4, 7, 9)
(1, 2, 5, 6, 8)
(1, 2, 5, 6, 9)
(1, 2, 5, 7, 8)
(1, 2, 5, 7, 9)
(1, 3, 4, 6, 8)
(1, 3, 4, 6, 9)
(1, 3, 4, 7, 8)
(1, 3, 4, 7, 9)
(1, 3, 5, 6, 8)
(1, 3, 5, 6, 9)
(1, 3, 5, 7, 8)
(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
```